# Implement multicast using the RxJS library with cleanup when the refcount is zero

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observer-pattern, multicast

I have some requirements as below in TypeScript:

```
Classs Observable
{
    // Should be a delay loader, will initialized only when subscriber, subscribes it.
    SendEvents()

    // When there are subscriber, uninitialize the library
    Uninitialize()
}

Class Subscriber {
    subscribeEvents()
    unsubscribeEvents
}

Subscriber subscriber1, Subscriber2 ..
```

How can I implement the same with multicast and subject using the [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) library in TypeScript?

I tried multiple articles, but the unsubscribe method is not working, which can make the refcount go to zero, and I can stop emitting events.

Comment: Have you tried using subscriber.complete() in your observable's subscriber method?

Comment: "will initialized only when subscriber, subscribes it" --> have you looked into the `defer` operator?

Comment: I can't call subscriber.complete , as the requirement is to have a function which will keep on collecting values and send to subscriber. I tried unsubscribe but it's getting called once per subscriber and from observable there is no way to have a reference count.

Comment: "Classs" (the first line in the sample code) appears to be a misspelling. Is it in the original?